# Doubts with a Lookup exercise

Tags: javascript, if-statement

As i was doing some js exercises in freeCodeCamp i came with this challenge.
We have an array of objects representing different people in our contacts lists.

A lookUpProfile function that takes firstName and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you.

The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.

If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.

If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"

If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No such property"
 And here's my ***finished*** code:

```
 //Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(myName, myProp){
// Only change code below this line
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

    if (contacts[i].firstName === myName){

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(myProp)){
        return contacts[i][myProp];
  } else {
        return "No such property";
      }

  } else {
        return "No such contact";}
  }

// Only change code above this line
}


// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

But it only returns "no such contact" which from my guess is that the first if is not evaluating to true. However, even the site answer is the same. Is there really anything wrong with the first comparison? What is it?

Comment: Try to evaluate your code line by line: you perform `if (contacts[i].firstName === myName){
` for the first item. It does not match `"Kristian"` so you go to the corresponding `else` branch: `return "No such contact";`. And you return from function. So you don't even check elements other than the first one.

Comment: I got it now i guess, it wasn't returning true because it was only checking the first array since i gave an else statement saying that if it didn't match the first compared property it should return false where it should first be checked all the arrays before returning false. All i had to do was to move the else to another line. Interesting, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just a minor problem, you are only comparing the first contact, and returning "no such contact" if the value does not match. Instead you should wait for the `for` loop to compare with all the contacts, and return "no such contact" if no match is found.

In code below, I have added a log statement along with the fix to show how it compares with all four contacts before returning the result. Of course, if a match is found, the program will return immediately.

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function lookUpProfile(myName, myProp) {
  var matchingContact = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    console.log("Comparing: " + contacts[i].firstName + " with " + myName);
    
    if (contacts[i].firstName === myName) {
      matchingContact = contacts[i];

      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(myProp)) {
        return contacts[i][myProp];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    } 
  }
  
  return "No such contact";
}


// Change these values to test your function
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Jake", "lastName"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "noSuchProp"));
```

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that, after @zerkms gave me his insight, thanks for answering as well, I'm feeling quite stupid for such a ridiculous mistake kk